# How to select value from dropdown which is not in <div> using selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below html code, all I want to click on the dropdown and select the first value.How can I achieve this.I am having issues when selecting the values from dropdown but was able to click the dropdown

```
<div id= "location-select-list" class="mb-list" role="role0">
    <mb-option id='1' class='classname' role='rolename' data-auto-id="dt1" aria-disabled="False" 1 </mb-option>
    <mb-option id='2' class='classname' role='rolename' data-auto-id="dt2"aria-disabled="False" 2 </mb-option>
```

I have tried this but not working.

```
#click on the dropdown--working

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                        xpath_0))).click()
#selecting 1st value from the dropdown value list--not working

xpath = "//div[@id='location-select-list']//mb-option[@data-auto-id='dt1']"
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                        xpath))).click()
```

Comment: 1) Do `//div[@id='location-select-list']//mb-option[@data-auto-id='dt1']` is the unique locator 2) Have you tried to use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable` especially for the second command? 3)Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Tried with `visibility_of_element_located` using `select`. but it's throwing error since the the dropdown is coded inside `div`.And yes the xpath is unique

Comment: I see no `select` n your HTML. So, if it is not there, why to use it?

Comment: The code that I provided doesn't include any `select`

Comment: But in the previously comment you mentioned "using `select`"..

Comment: @Prophet tried with `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                                                   xpath))).click()`. Its not selecting the first element.

Comment: The element my not be "clickable", try `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `element_to_be_clickable`.

Comment: @Jortega I have modified the code in the question. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Schan Yes, still not working?

Comment: No, it's not working.Unfortunately I can't share the url.

Comment: There are some helpful folks in this stackoverflow chatroom that might be able to help.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium

Comment: I think data-auto-id is the problem. Try using something else to select and click, like:
elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('classname')
elem_list[0].click()

Comment: @RobsonSampaio  tried `ele_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,
                                                              'mb-list'))) ele_list[0].click()`getting error `WebElement' object is not subscriptable
`

Comment: It happened because the element selected by the class_name 'mb-list' is not a list of elements. I'll write a answer, to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id= "location-select-list" class="mb-list" role="role0">
    <mb-option id='1' class='classname' role='rolename' data-auto-id="dt1" aria-disabled="False" 1 </mb-option>
    <mb-option id='2' class='classname' role='rolename' data-auto-id="dt2"aria-disabled="False" 2 </mb-option>
```

**Try this**

```
#click on the dropdown--working
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                        xpath_0))).click()

#my code
elem_list = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('classname') 
elem_list[0].click()
```

**Or**

```
elem_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mb-option[contains(@class, 'classname')]"):
elem[0].click()
```

Comment: It worked , thanks a lot. But there is one more issue. I have one more dropdown with the same class name like this.`<div id= "timezone-select-list" class="mb-list" role="role0">
    <mb-option id='3' class='classname' role='rolename' data-auto-id="dt3" aria-disabled="False" 1 </mb-option>
    <mb-option id='4' class='classname' role='rolename' data-auto-id="dt4"aria-disabled="False" 2 </mb-option>` Is there any way to refer to the top level `id` which is here `timezone-select-list`

Comment: You can use the same strategy creating a list of elements with the same classname and clicking on then as you like.
list_of_select = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
                                        //div[contains(@class, 'mb-list')] )))

list_of_select[0].click()
#then do whatever you have to
list_of_select[1].click()
#then do whatever you have to

(If you can't figure it out, please, create a new question and a take a looke as soon as possible)